# URL rewrite using Datapower Gateway

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup a URL rewrite using datapower. A request will come in from the customer in the following format - /products/{productid}/balance the {productid} will change for each customer and I need to change the format to be /balance/products/{productid} so that I don't need multiple context roots in Websphere. I have setup a MPGW but I am unable to put in the correct variables to change the request above which is supposed to be written in Perl (which I don't know) Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, ou need to create Policy with Request-Rule wich will contain XSL-transformation like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
  extension-element-prefixes="dp"
  exclude-result-prefixes="dp" >

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="originalUrl" select="dp:variable('var://service/URI')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="productId" select="substring-before(substring-after($originalUrl, '/products/'), '/balance')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="modifiedUrl" select="concat('/balance/products/', $productId)"/>

    <!--Set your own destination host ofc-->
    <dp:set-variable name="'var://service/routing-url'" value="concat('http://127.0.0.1', $modifiedUrl)"/> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

var://service/URI is a readonly service variable which contains URL-path from HTTP request
var://service/routing-url is a writable service variable wich contains a URI for routing